# find the source of crash in C program

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have a code base where the process running on linux is crashing in free and sometimes in malloc:

```
#0  0xffffe430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf7424e30 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xf7426765 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0xf7469d33 in malloc_printerr () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0xf746e7bc in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0xf6047e25 in myFree (mem_ptr=0x82165d8) at ../my_code/mylib.c:78
#6  0xf6014a10 in FreeBuffer (buffer=0x82042f8)
```

In the code I am not seeing anything fishy at the place where memory freeing is happening.
Function myFree() has nothing but a free() function call.

```
void FreeBuffer(struct MY_BUFFER *buffer)
{
    if (buffer)
    {
        myFree(buffer);
    }
}


void myFree(void *mem_ptr)
{

        free(mem_ptr);
}
```

I tried using MALLOC_CHECK_ but it was not of any help.

I suspect some where the heap is getting corrupted and want to find that.
Any hint to proceed to debug the process in such cases?

Comment: Where is the code? SSCE

Comment: Try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to catch memory problems early.

Comment: [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is also a good utility on *nix systems. [Simple tutorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/)

Comment: as mentioned above valgrind [http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html]

Comment: On Windows, if you're using VS you can add a data break point on the header of the allocated buffer (usually ~16 bytes before the returned address of `malloc()`) to trigger when it's changed.

Comment: sure, that your malloc is correct? or do you have an uninitialized pointer, or a static array/struct?

Comment: Having your `myFree()` and `FreeBuffer()` functions add unnecessary complexity here. The `NULL` test is unnecessary, as it is guaranteed to be included in `free()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is hard to be 100% sure but most probably you are trying to free memory twice. It's great that you are checking if pointer is not NULL before trying to free it

```
if (buffer)
    {
        myFree(buffer);
    }
```

but you are probably **NOT** setting pointer NULL after doing exact free job - that's my guess.

Check if you have something like this

```
struct MY_BUFFER *buffer;
//do something with buffer
FreeBuffer(buffer)
buffer = NULL;
```

You can do this as well inside `FreeBuffer()` function but to do so you will have to pass address of pointer AKA pointer to pointer so the definition will be like this `FreeBuffer(struct MY_BUFFER **buffer)`

Comment: I will check on this.